# How to recover from routef command on rhel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, command, rhel

By mistake I have executed routef command on linux machine. Please help me recover it before my manager blasts at me.

Comment: Top 10 "not to do"'s in production environment, duh

Comment: its not production. Its Dev env...!! manageable

Comment: Dev, no problem- it happens to the best sometimes. Good lesson to learn in Dev

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to disappoint you but there is no solution to this. The operation cannot be undone.

> *The routef script does not take any arguments and will simply flush the routing table down the drain. Beware! This means deleting all routes which will make your network unusable!* from [here](https://sarata.com/manpages/routef.8.html) or from [here](http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/8/routef/).

What you did is like running `/dev/null > /etc/network`. Cannot be undone. You can only solve it by adding all required entries manually.

Comment: what if we restart the machine ? its not on AWS :( . or add entries manually?

Comment: You have to add entries manually unless you have some backup files.

Comment: At this point of time I am unreachable that machine. Trying to contact system admin. Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: No problem, I hope you sort things out. Next time, take care what you execute ;). A rule of thumb: review each command you execute for one second. You might spend an hour in 10 years if you do that but will save you hours of work or even prevent unrepairable damage if you don't. Happened once to me that I created a `bin` folder (like in Java project and like `/bin` in Linux). I wanted to delete the Java folder, of course recursively and with `-f` because I don't like getting prompted if something is found that requires attention. But instead of `sudo -rf bin` I ran `sudo -rf /bin`(needed sudo)

Answer (score 0):

```
systemctl restart network && yum update
```

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.